# Servlet-Context not found : Spring 4 Hibernate 4 Maven JSF PrimeFaces in NetBeans

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans-8

To Start :
- I am a very very beginner in J2e, And this combination is almost perfect for a powerfull application, but is also perfect to blow a J2e starter.
- I searched for MANY answers and NO, none corrected this.

It is as simple as this :
- I repeated creating the app 8 times between Netbeans 8 and Eclipse Mars, I have all depedencies. The problem is with Servlet-Context. Tomcat throws a FileNotFound Error and once I remove this :

```
    <listener>
   <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
   <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

it works BUT shows not data from Database, (My whole app now is about showing user id with id = 1 on Database.)

The error in Tomcat :

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Can anyone please Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <listener>
   <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Removing this does the job. Spring 4 Problem.

Comment: strange, I thought you said you'd tried this as per my original suggestion/answer ?

Comment: Yes, I said I removed BOTH listenners.

Comment: But I said you should try removing one or the other not both, never mind at least it's been resolved

Comment: I did that before starting this thread but as i was a newbie i disnt knew if the code dont show a result because of the code it self or because of that line removal

Comment: Ok, you can you mark your answer as correct (click the 'tick' icon) so that the question is marked off as resolved? Helps others with similar issues also

Comment: Yes i can în 20 hours as per stack rules

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the **contextConfigLocation** to your web.xml so that it can locate your *applicationContext.xml* file.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: It's from this PDF tutorial that got that usage :
https://nvanhuong.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/spring_hibernate_jsf_primefaces_intergration.pdf

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa ok I see what you mean, can you try adding the context-param section to web.xml though? if doesn't still resolve your issue then I will delete this answer

Comment: No, it didn't. I tried removing one the both listeners, it throws a 500 error on Servelet.init()

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa I found this similar question/answer and looks like there another potential issue could be permissions-related, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694734/i-have-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml-but-application-cannot-find-it

Comment: Yes, I saw that before posting, all users (System and me) have all permissions to all folder files

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa is your web.xml of version 2.5? this is what it should be set to apparently, other than that I'm not sure what is wrong, did find this similar tutorial maybe you could cross-reference with the tutorial you are following perhaps find a solution/discrepancy that way http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

Comment: It seams that is a Spring 4 problem